# How to plot a readable table - Current output is so small

Tags: python

I am trying to plot a bar chart and with below a data table but I don't know how to deal with the size of the font and the scale of the table.

I tried to play with :

```
the_table.set_fontsize(18)
the_table.scale(1,10)
```

But it does not work.
The reproducible example is below

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
# Set styles
plt.style.use(['seaborn-paper', 'seaborn-whitegrid'])
plt.style.use(['seaborn'])
sns.set(palette='colorblind')
matplotlib.rc("font", family="Times New Roman", size=12)

labels = ['A AAAAA', 'BBB BBB', 'CCC CC', 'DD DDD', 'EEE EEE', 'FFF FFFFF', 'GGGGGG', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V']
a = [0.0, -5.46, -3.08, 0.07, -5.89, -5.27, -5.25, -2.02, -4.23, -1.17, -4.05, -4.74, -4.72, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.8, -3.79, -4.1, -1.94]

b = [0.0, -5.46, -3.08, 0.07, -5.89, -5.27, -5.25, -2.02, -4.23, -1.17, -4.05, -4.74, -4.72, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.8, -3.79, -4.1, -1.94]
bar_width = 0.20
data = [a,b]



colors = sns.color_palette(palette='colorblind')
columns = ('A AAAAA', 'BBB BBB', 'CCC CC', 'DD DDD', 'EEE EEE', 'FFF FFFFF', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V')

index = np.arange(len(labels))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))
plt.bar(index, a, bar_width)
plt.bar(index+bar_width+.02, b, bar_width)
the_table = plt.table(cellText=data,
          rowLabels=[' a ', ' b '],
          rowColours=colors,
          colLabels=columns,
          loc='bottom',
          bbox=[0, -0.225, 1, 0.2])
the_table.set_fontsize(40)
the_table.scale(3,50)
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1)

plt.ylabel('Some y label which effect the bottom padding!')
plt.xticks([])
plt.title('Some title')
plt.show()
```

OUTPUT :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `plt.table` is working the way it is intended to work. Your `the_table.set_fontsize(40)` line doesn't change things because, ["as long as auto font size has not been disabled, the value will be clipped such that the text fits horizontally into the cell."](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/table_api.html#matplotlib.table.Table.set_fontsize)

If you change your column names, to `columns = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V')` for example, then things look much better. If you still want to force a font size, you can use

```
the_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
the_table.set_fontsize(12)
```

after your `plt.table` command.